# Why does the presence of cointegration solve the problem of spurious correlation?

Tags: time-series, least-squares, cointegration, spurious-correlation

This question was originally posted on quantstackexchange:
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31501/why-does-the-presence-of-cointegration-solve-the-problem-of-spurious-correlation

Many of us are familiar with the connection between spurious correlation and its relationship to cointegration. Granger explains in his seminal 1974 paper "Spurious Regressions in Econometrics" how hypothesis testing on two time series that are I(1) can lead to significance tests that are very biased according to experimental results (resulting in far more "significant" correlations than there should be). Later, Philips (1986) showed with functional limit theory exactly why these I(1) time series led to biased results: because in fact there is no convergent asyptotic behavior for the correlation coefficient for these series (among other relevant statistics).

At this point, there seems to be a gap in my understanding. There are dozens of articles online saying that you can get around the spurious correlation problem for I(1) time series if they are also cointegrated. The explanation seems to be that since the error term is I(0), the usual assumptions of hypothesis testing for correlation are met. Of course, this makes intuitive sense, but I can't find anything that discusses this critical step of the argument in detail.

I am wondering if there is a reference that explains this relationship? @Quantuple mentioned that the property we are looking for is consitency of the OLS estimator. It seems pretty straighforward to show that the OLS estimator is consistent for two integrated time series only if the series are cointegrated, since otherwise the residual series has infinite variance. But is this a bidirectional implication, i.e. does the cointegration of these time series actually imply consistency?

Furthermore, one of the assumptions for OLS is that the residuals are not autocorrelated. Then should we have a stronger condition than cointegration, which requires the residuals to not only be stationary, but also pass the ljung-box test? This would seem to be a more natural requirement to me.

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer, but (1) cointegration yields superconsistency,; (2) autocorrelated errors do not prevent consistency (however, they affect the estimated error variance and thus coefficient standard errors and thus p-values of hypothesis tests).

Comment: wow, that is actually exactly the kind of answer I wanted. Concise and just enough information to do the rest of the research myself. Thanks

Comment: I am glad that helped. I would rather have written a full (although consise) answer, but there is just too much other stuff going on :)